# hex file reading in xv6

Tags: c, xv6

I am trying to modify this xv6 c file into a hex viewer.
I tried to utilize printf(%02X) but to no avail. I tried doing different combinations of placement for the printf(%02X) but it will either not print hex or just print "%02X" at the end of the file view.
For the printf functionality, it specifies these input arguments: Print to the given fd. Only understands %d, %x, %p, %s.
`void printf(int fd, const char *fmt, ...)`
Here is the code I am working with:

```
#include "types.h"
#include "stat.h"
#include "user.h"

char buf[512];

void
hex(int fd)
{
  int n;

  while((n = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0) {
   if (write(1, buf, n) != n) {
     printf(1, "hex: write error\n");
     exit();
     }
    printf(n,"%02X");
   } 
   if(n < 0){
     printf(1, "hex: read error\n");
     exit();
   }

}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int fd, i;

  if(argc <= 1){
    hex(0);
    exit();
  }

  for(i = 1; i < argc; i++){
    if((fd = open(argv[i], 0)) < 0){
      printf(1, "hex: cannot open\n", argv[i]);
      exit();
    }
    hex(fd);
    close(fd);
  }
  exit();
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with printf taking a file descriptor as its first argument... Can you link to a reference for that? I thought it was just a format string then varargs... Even so, how is 1 a meaningful file descriptor?

Comment: @vicatcu That's how the xv6 libc works; it's not standard C. (Descriptor 1 is standard output, most likely)

Comment: OP, you're trying to write to whatever descriptor is held in n, which since it's the return value of `read()`, is very unlikely to be an open descriptor. And you're missing an argument for the `%X` format.

Comment: @vicatcu Indeed, xv6's printf is not standard, its prototype is `void printf(int, const char*, ...);`, and it's defined here: https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/master/printf.c

Answer (score 0):

As you found yourself, in xv6, `printf` is very limited and you can't use `%02x` modifier. You have to restrict your self to `%x` (or you can extend the `printf` function, but it's an exercise beyond what is asked to you.

For each character, you have to call `printf(1, "%x ", the_character);`
For characters for `0x10` to `0xFF`, it will print two character, for characters under `0x10`, you have to add the extra `0`.

--
To print char by char, you need a `for` loop on the buffer you got after the `read` call. Add some space and LF to improve visibility and you're done.

```
void hex(int fd)
{
  char buf[16];

  int n, i;

  while((n = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (buf[i] < 0x10) {
            printf(1, "0");
        }
        printf(1,"%x ", buf[i]);
    }
    printf(1, "\n");
   } 
}
```